# celery-beat won't trigger tasks when DatabaseScheduler: Schedule changed

Tags: celery, django-celery, celerybeat

I have celery beat and celery to do some processing steps in bulk.
but celery-beat won't trigger tasks for a few second when DatabaseScheduler: Schedule changed

```
    PeriodicTask.objects.create(name=str(instance.identifier),
                                    task='TaskChecker',
                                    enabled=True, crontab_id=cron_on.id,
                                    one_off=False,args=json.dumps([None,None,id]))
```

Can anybody help?

Version info:

> django-celery-beat==2.5.0